# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : CBPeripheral]' with an index of type 'Int'

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth

I can't set the main label of the cell to the name of the corresponding peripheral.

help me to find a solution!!

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll1M6.png)

```swift
var activeCentralManager: CBCentralManager?
var peripheralDevice: CBPeripheral?
var devices: Dictionary<String, CBPeripheral> = [:]
var deviceName: String?
var devicesRSSI = [NSNumber]()
var devicesServices: CBService!
var deviceCharacteristics: CBCharacteristic!  

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return devices.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Let's get a cell.
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    // Turn the device dictionary into an array.
    let discoveredPeripheralArray = devices as? [String : CBPeripheral]
    //println(discoveredPeripheralArray.count)

    // Set the main label of the cell to the name of the corresponding peripheral.
    if let cell = cell{
        if let name = discoveredPeripheralArray?[indexPath.row].name{
            if let textLabelText = cell.textLabel{
                textLabelText.text = name
            }
            if let detailTextLabel = cell.detailTextLabel{
                detailTextLabel.text = devicesRSSI[indexPath.row].stringValue
            }
        }
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: println? What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: its from an old version of swift, I'm trying to convert the code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
// Turn the device dictionary into an array.
let discoveredPeripheralArray = devices as? [String : CBPeripheral]
```

`[String : CBPeripheral]` is not an array. It is a dictionary. So `discoveredPeripheralArray` is a dictionary too. And you cannot magically turn a dictionary into an array.

Comment: so how can I fix it?

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand what "fix" means. A dictionary and an array don't have anything to do with each other. When you say `discoveredPeripheralArray?[indexPath.row]` you clearly imagine that you have some CBPeripherals in a fixed order — an array — so that you can show the name of each one in a row of the table. But that is _not_ what you have. You have acquired or stored your CBPeripherals in a dictionary. A dictionary has no order, so you cannot use it as the basis of a table view's rows. So I cannot imagine what you're trying to do.

Comment: how can I convert the dictionary into an Array of Values?

Comment: You need to have a _plan_ for turning this orderless dictionary into an ordered array. A dictionary itself has no order. So what should the order of the array be? You have not revealed that. When you do, you can "fix" this problem.

Comment: _What_ is your plan. _What should the order be?_

Comment: i want to create a table view for the list of bluetooth devices

Comment: In. What. Order?

Comment: i don't care about the order

Comment: You might not care but you have to _say_ what it should be, because the dictionary has no order.

Comment: and how can I order?

Comment: I would suggest using the CBPeripheral’s `identifier.uuidString`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the error line with this:

```swift
let discoveredPeripheralArray = devices.keys.sorted
```

You'll need to make sure `devicesRSSI` matches the same order, though.